# Undefined values React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to achieve making a suspend user button via updating the values of the user the status to Suspended, but the problem is the status is defined but other values are undefined did I do something wrong or is there any way to update the values to make the other variable like a name not required?

This is what I mean:

[image]

This is my code:

```
const User = (props) => (
  <>
    <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title="Action">
      <Dropdown.Item>
        <a
          href="user"
          onClick={() => {
            props.onSubmit(props.user[0]);
          }}
        >
          <i className="fas fa-trash"></i> Suspend
        </a>
      </Dropdown.Item>
    </DropdownButton>
  </>
);

export default class Users extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = { users: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:5000/users/")
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ users: response.data });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }



  onSubmit(id) {
    const user = {
      name: this.state.name,
      password: this.state.password,
      email: this.state.email,
      storeName: this.state.storeName,
      storeUrl: this.state.storeUrl,
      date: this.state.date,
      status: "Suspended",
    };

    console.log(user);

    axios
      .post("http://localhost:5000/users/update/" + id, user)
      .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
  }
  userList(currentuser) {
    return (
      <User
        user={currentuser}
        key={currentuser[0]}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
      />
    );
  }
  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        name: "_id",
        options: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "name",
        label: "Name",
        options: {
          filter: true,
          sort: true,
        },
      },
      {
        name: "Action",
        options: {
          customBodyRender: (value, tableMeta, updateValue) => {
            return <>{this.userList(tableMeta.rowData)}</>;
          },
        },
      },
    ];
    const { users } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
          <MUIDataTable data={users} columns={columns} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the `this.state.storeUrl`?  the state has the only user propriety

Comment: hi @vincenzopalazzo it is one of the values like name, email, storeName

Comment: ops I miss some code here sorry!

Comment: no problem HEHHEHE

Comment: The state of `User` is `{ users: [] }`, yet in the `onSubmit` you do this: `this.state.name` ....

Comment: so that's why but how do I do solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define nor set the User's individual attributes' values in the state! So, no wonder they show up as undefined, when you try to read them...

The simplest solution would be:

```
onSubmit(id) {
    //let user = this.state.users.find(user => user.id === id); // find by id
    let user = this.state.users[id]; // find by index

    if (user) {
        user.status = 'Suspended';

        console.log(user);

        axios
          .post("http://localhost:5000/users/update/" + id, user)
          .then((res) => console.log(res.data));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering really appreciate it

Comment: Cannot set property 'status' of undefined this is the error when I put this code

Comment: You have to put it all in an if-statement (edited my answer). Also, modify the `find` function so that it matches the user you're working on.

Comment: Hi @k-wasilewski what do u mean modify?

Comment: In the body of a js `find` function you define the criteria for an object you're looking for. I assumed any of your User entities (received from api) has an `id` attribute, but since you say the function returns undefined, probably you have to define the criteria differently.

Comment: oh I see thank u but im not that experience can u please guide me?

Comment: By 'modify' I mean identify the particular user (from the users within the `this.state.users`) you want to submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227440/discussion-between-alif-khan-and-k-wasilewski).

Comment: Here you go. So your `(id)` is not really an id, it's just and index of an array...

Comment: oh now I get it

Comment: I can't exactly debug it for you, please do it yourself and tell me what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: lets chat in the chatroom